# keeping the id found when a new object fails uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been trying to work this out for a while and I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I was hoping there would be a value in request.env that I could use, or some obvious way to override the uniqueness validator to accomplish this, but I have not been able to get it.

So when the uniqueness validator fails, I want to be able to capture the id of the record with the duplicate info in the db so I can just use that instead.  Has anyone done this?

Comment: All the uniqueness validator does is validate uniqueness; AFAIK if you want to hang behavior off of that you'd need to write a custom validator. It may be easier not to do this as a validation, though, since you're not really validating-you're doing a lookup and altering flow based on whether or not something is found.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I was just thinking that maybe if I think outside the box and just don't use a validation it will be much easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing with a validator, you could use [find_or_create_by](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/lianaleahy/2008/05/19/find_or_create/) instead.  It'll use the old object if it already exists, or create a new one if it doesn't - and it does all the work for you!

Hope this helps!

PS:  Here are the [Official Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) - the section you want is "Dynamic Attribute-Based Finders", a little ways down.  I just think the first link is more useful...

Comment: Thanks a lot Xavier!  I ended up implementing it in the controller using regular old find_by and doing it in two steps, but you are right find_or_create_by is exactly what I was looking for.  It is a bit sloppy because this qualifies as 'business logic' in my controller, but I think I could firgure out how to work it into a model...